# how to use httpwebrequest to login to site in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i want to login to site with my account but using vb.net "httpwebrequest"
this is the header :

```
http://www.alexasurfing.com/login?task=user.login

POST /login?task=user.login HTTP/1.1
Host: www.alexasurfing.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.alexasurfing.com/login
Cookie: __cfduid=d09a17b9b5acf54646546541471462027; refid=14786;
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 159
username=GMAL%40gmail.com&password=PASWW&remember=yes
HTTP/1.1 303 See other
Date: Wed, 17 Aug 2016 19:30:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17
Location: /dashboard/profile
Server: cloudflare-nginx
```

i dont know how to use httpwebrequest to login to the site with my account ?

Answer (score 0):

See the example here:

[HTTP request with post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)

your post data is: `username=GMAL%40gmail.com&password=PASWW&remember=yes`

**Note**: You are sending plain text password over http. If there's an https option you should use that.